# Контроль скорости Vector2

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру типа понга, шарик отталкивается от коллайдера за счёт "Bounciness = 1" динамический Rigidbody.
Возникла проблема, что в зависимости от угла соприкосновения, увеличивается или уменьшается скорость шарика, как задать постоянную скорость в независимости от угла, или хотя бы лимит скорости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
v = v.normalized * l;
```

где `Vector2 v` - скорость, а `float l` - модуль вектора скорости, которую мы хотим достичь.

Работает так: `normalized` возвращает сонаправленный вектор длиной 1, который мы умножаем на число, и длина вектора становится `l`.